# React useEffect is only updating one of the values

Tags: reactjs

I realise that there is most likely a very simple explanation for this, only I can't quite figure it out. I'm making to API calls `getNarrativeReferences` and `getNarrativeHeaders` these return two separate values which go into two arrays in `searchState`. The problem being that on page load only ever one or the other is updated. Rendering either the headers or references but never both.

Should I refactor the API to return both references and headers in the same request. Or can this be arranged such that both are indeed updated?

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("QueryParam Value: " + id);
  if (id) {
    getNarrativeReferences(id).then((response) => {
      setSearchState({ headers: searchState.headers, references: response });
    });
    getNarrativeHeaders(id).then((response) => {
      setSearchState({ headers: response, references: searchState.references });
    });
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: You've got two API calls updating the same exact state properties. If the data is not the same then you need two different pieces of state - I can't see where the "two arrays" you mention in your question are supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function inside setState, to get prev state and merge that with new state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("QueryParam Value: " + id);
  if (id) {
    getNarrativeReferences(id).then((response) => {
      setSearchState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        headers: searchState.headers,
        references: response,
      }));
    });
    getNarrativeHeaders(id).then((response) => {
      setSearchState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        headers: response,
        references: searchState.references,
      }));
    });
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Almost perfect. I just needed to remove `headers: searchState.headers` in the first call and `references:searchState.references` in the second call. Thank you!